# Making resources theme dependent

Tags: android, android-theme

Now that we have two Icons (Dark and Light) as described in [ActionBar Icon Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_action_bar.html).

```
@drawable/ic_search_light 
@drawable/ic_search_dark
```

How to reference these Icons in XML menu resource:

`<item android:title="Search" android:icon="`Which drawable here ?
`"/>`

Every time switch Application theme between Light and Dark, Do I have to update all these drawable references ?

Comment: Create a Theme for Holo Light and one for Holo dark. Everytime the user picks an other Theme, you can switch between them.

Comment: That doesn't explain how do I reference the menu Icon, This is not a style-able widget.

Comment: Actually it does - what I meant was: create 2 Themes/Menus. In the first you can reference all holo light icons, in the second all the holo dark icons. So if your user decides to switch, you just have to change the theme(and not all the icons).

Comment: Updated my findings in the answer.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

There's a way to define android *drawables* (and many other elements found in *res/values*) to be Theme dependent.

Lets suppose we have two *drawables*, menu icons in this case:

```
res/drawable/ic_search_light.png
res/drawable/ic_search_dark.png
```

And we want to use `ic_search_dark.png` for Application theme which is default `Theme` or extends it, Similarly, we want `ic_search_light.png` if our Application theme changes to default `Theme.Light` or some theme extending it.

Define a general attribute with a unique name in */res/attrs.xml* like:

```
<resources>
<attr name="theme_dependent_icon" format="reference"/>
</resources>
```

This is a global attribute and format type is reference, In case of a Custom View it can be defined along with style-able attributes:

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="custom_menu">
        <attr name="theme_dependent_icon" format="reference"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Next, define two Themes, extending default `Theme` and `Theme.Light` (or themes that inherit from these) in *res/styles.xml* or *res/themes.xml*:

```
<resources>
    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="theme_dependent_icon" >@drawable/ic_search_dark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTheme.Light" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="theme_dependent_icon" >@drawable/ic_search_light</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Finally, use the reference attribute we define to refer to these icons. In this case, we use while defining a menu layout

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:title="Menu Item"  android:icon="?attr/theme_dependent_icon"/>
</menu>
```

`?attr` refers to an attribute of current theme in use.

Now, we can use above two themes for application:

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

or

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme.Light">
```

and corresponding resources will be used accordingly.

Theme can also be applied in Code, by setting it at the very beginning of Activity's `onCreate()`.

**UPDATE**

Method to access these theme dependent resources from code is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3679026/1531054).

Comment: So goes for all theme dependent resources (pretty much). Good summary.

Comment: This logic looked over months very weird to me and I've never seen a answer which gave the same short overview as you give with yours. Great explained! Thank you so much. I guess things in xml will get more clear for me, right now. :)

Comment: Works perfectly for colors as well!