# Firebase notification icon color in AndroidManifest.xml for night mode

Tags: android, firebase, notifications

I have `AndriodManifest.xml` with the following values:

```xml
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"    
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_notification" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/defaultNotificationColor"/>
```

Then I have `colors.xml` in 2 folders - `values/colors.xml` and `values-night/colors.xml`. I override `defaultNotificationColor` Inside the `values-night` one with

```xml
<resources>
    <color name="defaultNotificationColor">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

But this setup is ignored, and the color of the notification is the one from the `values/colors.xml`.

The value is properly set when accessed from the code:

```kotlin
resources.getString(R.color.defaultNotificationColor) // this is OK
```

Is it even possible to color the icon in the manifest?

The SDKs setup:

```
compileSdkVersion = 29
targetSdkVersion = 29
minSdkVersion = 19
```

Comment: I think this could be useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/12339924/8041528

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the way how auto dark mode works on Android 10 and above

The color string under `values-night/colors.xml` will be used only if your app is using the dark mode(check using `AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode` is `MODE_NIGHT_NO` or `MODE_NIGHT_YES` for light and dark modes respectively).

If it is not under the dark mode it will continue using the color string under `values/colors.xml` which is what is happening in your case

You can also check if you have supported the default night theme on Android 10 and above [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme#support-dark-theme)