# How to make android WebView adaptive?

Tags: android, html, web, webview

I have html5 with JS. It looks pretty good but is too big for (Nexus 5) screen and WebView becomes scrollable. 
I am looking long time for solution to make this view adaptive.

```
WebView mWebView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gamelayout);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#001A0F"));
        mWebView.zoomOut();
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/anim1/Untitled-1.html");

    }
```

Comment: That problem has nothing to do with the `WebView`. The problem lies in the HTML content you are trying to display inside the `WebView`.

Comment: You should read about responsive web design and then modify your HTML content accordingly.

Comment: you have to make changes in the html content for resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments mention, you need to change the html.

Use the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083627/android-reference-the-value-of-an-attribute-in-the-currently-applied-theme-fro) to read the colors you want. For me, i needed to read `colorSurface`, i.e.:

```
        int bgColorResId = R.attr.colorSurface;
        TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
        getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(bgColorResId, typedValue, true);
        int bgColor = typedValue.data
```

Then I needed to convert that [int to a hexa string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506708/android-convert-color-int-to-hexa-string).

```
String colorStr = String.format("#%06X", 0xFFFFFF & bgColor)
```

Finally, you need to add this to your html string, e.g.

```
"<body bgcolor=\"" + colorStr + "\">"
```

You can do that for text color as well. Put the text color here

```
<style type="text/css">
body { color: #TEXTCOLOR };
</style>
```